# Hibernate Virtual Map Key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Say I have a table(T) of columns: `a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2`

```
@Entity 
class T {
     @ElementCollection
     @VirtualMapKey
     Map<String, Foo> foos
}

@Embeddable
class Foo {
     String v1
     String v2
}
```

If I want to get `a1` field of the T instance then I can invoke `t.foos['a'].v1`. I wonder if I can achieve this with Hibernate 5.1 or JPA 2.1. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first shot would be to rework your entities:

```
@Entity 
class T {
     @AttributeOverrides(value = {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "v1", column = @Column(name = "a1")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "v2", column = @Column(name = "a2"))
    })
     Foo a;

     @AttributeOverrides(value = {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "v1", column = @Column(name = "b1")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "v2", column = @Column(name = "b2"))
    })
     Foo b;


     @AttributeOverrides(value = {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "v1", column = @Column(name = "c1")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "v2", column = @Column(name = "c2"))
    })
     Foo c;
}
```

and then you can do this simply `t.a.v1, t.a.v2,  t.b.v1, t.b.v2` etc.   You have fixed number of columns in your table - just reflect it in the mapping.